# About SQL pivot query

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

This is static pivot query:

```
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
         PI.PRODID||' '||' ('||PI.PRODNAME||' - '||PI.PACKSIZE||')' PNAME,I.SIA_ID, IP.SALES_QTY
     FROM 
         DIS_INVOICE_INFO I, DIS_INVOICE_PRODUCT IP, MKT_PROD_INFO PI
     WHERE
         I.SLNO = IP.SLNO
         AND PI.PRODID = IP.PRODID) s
PIVOT  
    (SUM(SALES_QTY) 
        FOR SIA_ID IN (10080, 10084, 10082)
    ) pvt
```

But I want a dynamic query.

Like:

```
......
PIVOT 
    (SUM(SALES_QTY) 
         FOR SIA_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SIA_ID FROM DIS_INVOICE_INFO) 
    ) pvt
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[image]You didn't mention about your `DBMS`, I don't know for the other `DBMS` systems but for `Oracle` you may make it dynamic provided you're producing `XML` results as in the following case :

```
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    (SELECT PI.PRODID||' '||' ('||PI.PRODNAME||' - '||PI.PACKSIZE||')' PNAME,
            I.SIA_ID, IP.SALES_QTY
       FROM DIS_INVOICE_INFO I 
       INNER JOIN DIS_INVOICE_PRODUCT IP 
          ON (I.SLNO = IP.SLNO)
       INNER JOIN MKT_PROD_INFO PI
          ON (PI.PRODID = IP.PRODID)) s
PIVOT XML 
    (SUM(SALES_QTY) 
        FOR SIA_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SIA_ID FROM DIS_INVOICE_INFO)
    ) pvt;
```

By using the following `DDL` statements ;

```
create table DIS_INVOICE_INFO(SIA_ID int, SLNO int);
create table DIS_INVOICE_PRODUCT(PRODID int, SALES_QTY int, SLNO int);
create table MKT_PROD_INFO(PRODID int,PRODNAME varchar(90),PACKSIZE int);

insert all 
       into DIS_INVOICE_INFO values(10080,1);
       into DIS_INVOICE_PRODUCT values(1,100,1);
       into MKT_PROD_INFO values(1,'Milk',200);
select * from dual;
```

You get the following results for the above `SQL-Select` statement :

```
   PNAME       SIA_ID_XML
  ------------ ---------- 
  (Milk - 200)   <CLOB>
```

where `<CLOB>` is

```
<PivotSet><item><column name = "SIA_ID">10080</column>
<column name = "SUM(SALES_QTY)">100</column></item></PivotSet>
```

P.s. You cannot use `PIVOT` dynamically *without* `XML` option, I mean need to list all arguments explicitly within `IN` clause as in your case.

Comment: Oracle database